# Unable to get Python requests with API token

Tags: python-3.x, rest, api-key

This is my code:

`import requests`

### API key correct

`api_key = c87cabcf1b479b807a7b3ba8xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

```
headers = {    
    'Accept': 'application/json',  
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Token token=api_key'
}
```

### Getting a List of serves from this API

`r = requests.get('https://myserver/api/v1.1/server/', headers = headers, verify=False)`

`print(r.json())`

`print (r.status_code)`

#### I am getting the error below. I checked my token correct one and not expires.

r.json() : **{'error': {'code': 'error', 'description': 'Authentication credentials were not provided.'}}**

r.status_code :  **401**

I missed somewhere in the header.

Comment: By concern here is, I guess you shouldn't be disclosing your API key

Comment: May be an issue with the Authorization header, you have define Token token="", which might be wrong.

Can you please provide the api in postman so I can review the API and help you to solve this.

Comment: can u get this working using CURL? Do same headers work with CURL command?

Comment: CURL it working,but  I need python. 
I used same key. not working for python
 curl -X GET https://hostname/api/v1.1/filers/ -k -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Token 623598ngna9834j3457cb93f1da0' | sed s/","/\\n/g

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem is may be in your third line of header. Try it like this.

```
'Authorization': 'Token ' + api_key
```

Comment: HI Thanks for your reply. I tried but i am getting same error

headers = {

   'Accept': 'application/json',

  'Authorization': 'Token'+ api_key

}```


My error :

```{'error': {'code': 'error', 'description': 'Authentication credentials were not provided.'}}```

Comment: he meant 'Token ' + api_key with a space between the word Token and the api key

Comment: Supper it working, Thanks very much. I missed the space.